# Reusing functions do not work

Tags: r

Function :

```
myFunc=function(from) {
           ss=unlist(strsplit(from,":"))
           as.numeric(ss[1])*24*60+as.numeric(ss[2])*60+as.numeric(ss[3])
}
```

works perfectly in this case :

```
myFunc("61:35:00")
myFunc("61:36:00")
```

but only 1 time works (on first string of csv file) in I needed to use case :

```
setClass('myTime')
setAs("character","myTime", myFunc(from) )
art=read.csv2("file.csv", colClasses=c('myTime') )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function isn't vectorised and just returns a single value based on the first 3 values in the vector `ss`.

You could either `lapply / sapply` your `myFunc()` to multiple values:

```
x <- c("61:35:00", "61:36:00")

sapply(x,myFunc)
#61:35:00 61:36:00 
#   89940    90000
```

...or rewrite it to do this internally:

```
myFunc2=function(from) {
  ss=strsplit(from,":")
  sapply(
    ss,
    function(x) as.numeric(x[1])*24*60+as.numeric(x[2])*60+as.numeric(x[3])
  )
}

myFunc2(x)
#[1] 89940 90000
```

...or use `Vectorize`, which is probably not overly prudent in this case:

```
Vectorize(myFunc)(x)
#61:35:00 61:36:00 
#   89940    90000
```